# BIND Nameserver - $ORIGIN in zonefile include always appends to its previous value

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, subdomain, dns-zone

There is a a basic zonefile for "example.com" with an include of another zonefile for the subdomain, which has another include for each server.
Now the usage of $ORIGIN without trailing dot always appends to its previous value.
For simplicity i have renamed the includes without using the full path.

**Question**: Is it possible to reset the previous $ORIGIN value?

Current Configuration:

*zonefile for example.com*

```
$ORIGIN subdomain.example.com.
$INCLUDE subdomain
```

*subdomain include*

```
$ORIGIN srv1
$INCLUDE srv1

$ORIGIN srv2
$INCLUDE srv2
```

*srv1/srv2 include*

```
@   IN  A       127.0.0.1
```

**Result:**

```
srv1.subdomain.example.com // SUCCESS: resolves correctly
srv2.subdomain.example.com // ERROR: does not resolve

srv2.srv1.subdomain.example.com // SUCCESS: resolves correctly
```

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to revert to a previous origin value.

You'll have to just set the origin to the new value that you want, either in the form of an absolute name (ie, with a trailing dot) or relative to the current origin (which does not seem to fit what you want in the question).

Comment: Thanks! Sadly absolute naming is not an option since the include must be present for different zones.